# CodeIgniter adding page doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have taken over a project written in CodeIgniter, which I have never used before. I have added a new file to views/pages called features.php, and have read on the internet that to make it accessible, I need to create a function in the controller file that will render the page.

I have tried the following:

```
public function features()
{
    $this->render('template', 'pages/features');
}
```

However, when I try to open features.php, it gives me 404. How can I fix that?

## Update 1 - Class

Here is the controller's class code:

```
class Pages extends MY_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('setting_model', 'setting');
    $this->load->model('order_model', 'order');
    $this->load->model('page_model', 'page');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('inflector', 'string'));
}

public function index()
{
    $settings = $this->setting->get_settings();
    $data['document_price'] = $settings->document_price;
    $this->render('template', 'pages/index', $data); 
}

    //This works fine
public function about_us()
{
    $this->render('template', 'pages/about_us');
}

    //Here is the problem, although it follows the same pattern as about_us()
public function features()
{
    $this->render('template', 'pages/features');
}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using $this->render I guess you are using the template library. I think you should be using:

```
public function features()
{
   $this->template->set_template('template');
   $this->template->write_view('pages/features');    
   $this->template->render();
}
```

Comment: OK, from where did you get the syntax $this->render ? Normally you would load a view with $this->load->view('name_of_view',$data); so there must be some sort of templating library installed. Have you checked other controller syntax?

Comment: furthermore you are telling me you try to open features.php. In CI the URI convention is /controller_class_name/function_name (and sometimes preceded by /index.php ) so you shouldn't put .php at the end and instead write /controller_name/features

Comment: It is used in another function to call the about us page: public function about_us(){$this->render('template', 'pages/about_us');} This works fine somehow...

Comment: @Charles when you say it works what is the url you are typing to see the aboutus page ?

Comment: it is just www.link.com/about_us; I am trying the same with www.link.com/features, to no avail...

Comment: Then I suggest you to check the /application/config/routes.php file as a function in the 1:st URI segment is not default CI routing. Might need to copy the syntax for about_us to features

Comment: The routes.php suggestion helped me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The php files contained in `/views` are not directly accessible by typing in some URL. CodeIgniter is an MVC framework. That means that your URLs are mapped to your controllers and the controllers call the views.

What is the name of the class that this function is encapsulated in? Please post the entire class and not just the `features()` function and we can help you out. If you're working locally, the default mapping to call controllers is: `http://localhost/appname/controller/function/param1/param2/etc`.

The `$this->render()` function is not vanilla CodeIgniter syntax, you either inherited a project that is using a templating library, or, there is a sibling `render()` function inside the controller class.

Check your `config/routes.php` file as well and consider posting it.

If you want to diagnose the issue, try pinpointing by removing the call to `$this->render()` and instead using CodeIgniter's native `$this->load->view('pages/features')` function. If this works, we can be sure it's the library or `render()` call.

Comment: I have added the class in the question, see above. Thanks so far!

Comment: Can you make anything of it? It seems that the function is just not called... Where are the functions normally called from?

Comment: the `render()` function is inside `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

Comment: Yes, try calling in your url: `http://link.com/pages/features` If I were to guess, there is a route set up in `config/routes.php` that directs any traffic to `http://link.com/about_us` to the `Pages` controller and `about_us` function. If you want to mimic that behaviour, so that `http://link.com/features` is active, you'll have to add another route.

Comment: Please take the time to understand what has happened here though; It is absolutely crucial that you understand that the names of your controllers are mapped to the URL. The format is always: `http://link.com/controller_name/function_name` so when you called `http://link.com/pages/features` so it fired the `features()` function in the `Pages` controller. [A must read for you](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)